# не правильно располагается ячейка в гриде

Tags: css-grid

1. должен быть 1 ряд
2. первая ячейка желтого цвета
3. вторая ячейка прозрачная
4. третья ячейка желтого цвета

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 256px 50px 100px;
  grid-template-areas: 'a . a';
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.a{
  grid-area: a;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="a">a</div>
</div>
```

Comment: И что неправильного? Элемент не может разорвать себя на две части.

Comment: @hu-fo я прочитал что Вы можете указать пустую ячейку, используя точку (.) или серию точек без пробелов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> я прочитал что Вы можете указать пустую ячейку, используя точку (.) или серию точек без пробелов.

Да, но тогда нужно сделать вот так: `a . b`, и положить в   `grid` ещё один элемент. С одним элементом будет работать только так:

`. . a`

или

`a . .`

или

`a a .`

или

`. a a`

или если будет несколько строк

`a a .`

`a a .`

и т.д